# Consume WCF from Android

Tags: wcf

I have an WCF API that is working on IIS when called by a Windows application using  web SeviceReference.  I am not trying to get it work when called by an Android application.  I would assume I could "test" the otherwise working API from a web browser, or from Fiddler, to make sure my calling syntax was correct, but when I try, I get a 404 error.

My Webservice Web.config serviceModel is as follows:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>

<services>
  <service name="TaskTrackerAppService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="TaskTrackerAppService.IAppWebService"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration=""></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

When I enter into a browser:

```
http://localhost:51276/AppWebService.svc and 
http://localhost:51276/AppWebService.svc?wsdl
```

I do get the expected WSDL response. (From both my localhost and from the hosted web server where this WCF has been running.)

So next I add in the request for:

```
 http://localhost:51276/AppWebService.svc/SayHello/1000
```

Where SayHello will return confirmation that userId 1000 exists.  And I get back:

```
404 - The resource cannot be found
```

I've also tried:

```
http://localhost:51276/AppWebService.svc/SayHello?userId=1000 etc.
```

Help. I'm stuck.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you know, we need to generate the client proxy class to call the traditional wcf service. We could use the following ways. 
 1. Add the service reference. Or use the svcutil.exe to generate the client proxy class.
 2. Use the Channel factory.
While these methods all need to client proxy class. If you want to invoke a specific operation in the form of a URL, you need to host WCF as http-web mode. This requires us to use webservicehost or webhttpbinding.  I have made a demo. Wish it is useful to you.
Server.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:9090");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
        Console.ReadKey();
        host.Close();
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SayHi(int id);
}
public class MyService : IService
{
    public string SayHi(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wow, I have been called");
        return "Hello Stranger "+id;
    }
}
```

**Result.**
[image]
More details about wcf web http-mode service(Restful).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model

Answer (score 0):

You have an endpoint configuration for

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

but none of your endpoints use it.

Pick an endpoint and **use** this behavior. Right now, it's dead, unused XML.