# connecting to wcf service on local pc from android studio application

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I have an android studio program as client and wcf service on local  pc as server side to manage sql sever database.
when I test my wcf service in Fiddler by GET method, Fiddler can not return any result .also on web browser display an error.

[Fiddler] The connection to 192.168.xx.x failed
Error: NetworkUnreachable(0X2743)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException a socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 192.168.xx.x:8080
(xx.x is  part of my full ip address has real value )

my OS is windows 10 x64

at other side my android app can not get any data from server. on android studio I set url to "http://192.168.xx.x:8080/MyWebService.svc"
and used url.openConnection()
please help me
thanks a lot

Comment: It seems that the services is not hosted properly, see my previous demo,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911054/consume-wcf-from-android/51946279#51946279                     
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200663/how-can-i-use-a-wcf-service/53203436#53203436

Comment: More details about WCF web-mode service, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model